Strange Artifacts on Geo
During the process of editing this geo, it has become very faceted and has strange shadows. The normals appear to be fine, but no matter how much I try to re-topo it, it still looks strange. Any thoughts?


1 - You have "non-quad" faces // 2 - you have disconnected faces (or split edges), you could try to merge by distance // 3 - you have more than 2 faces coming out of some edges (faces hidden inside the volume)
